# How to let TypeScript know the keys of my object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I type this using TypeScript:

```
const k = {
  container: {
   width: '100%',
  },
}
```

When I use intellisense, TypeScript seems cool to figure out that my object `k` has a property named `container`. And it works fine. Now, I want to restrict the values of the properties so I declare an interface:

```
interface StyleSet {
   [key: string]: React.CSSProperties
}
```

And now I add the type to the previous object, so we have:

```
const k: StyleSet = {
  container: {
   width: '100%',
  },
}
```

And everything works fine. Now intellisense can recognize, and TypeScript enforces that the values of the properties of object `k` hare of type `React.CSSProperties`.

However, and now comes the problem, now intellisense (and TypeScript!?) do not recognice any more the names of the properties in my `k` object. i.e. when I type `k.` it does not suggest (and seems to ignore) what I type afterwards. So I can type `k.potatoe` and use that value without any problem (of course, the value is undefined / null ) but TypeScript does not prompt any error any more.

Question: How can I tell TypeScript, the values of the properties are all of type React.CSSProperties, but when I use the object, still restrict the names of the properties? i.e. so that I can only type `k.container`.

I was searching online through plenty of documentation and examples of TypeScript but seems this is impossible. I tried with interfaces, types, Record, ReadOnly...

Notice that the keys of the objects are not known. For instance one could be:

```
const a: StyleSet = {
  potato:{
    width: '100%',
  },
}
```

while another object could be:

```
const b: StyleSet = {
  ketchup: {
    width: 'auto',
  },
}
```

Also notice that there is a partial solution for this, using `ReturnType` TypeScript can do what I want but I would need to wrap every object in a function. And I find it non-sense too.

Any idea is welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

```
type PossibleKeys = 'container' | 'foo' | 'bar';

type StyleSet = {
    // Question mark makes them optional properties.
    // Otherwise TypeScript will require all keys in `PossibleKeys` to present.
    [key in PossibleKeys]?: React.CSSProperties
}

const k: StyleSet = {
    container: {
        width: '100%',
    },
}

// Now when you type `k.`, you will see three suggestions listed above.
```

Try it in this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUIBnZ4AIwBskBpJa5nAC8BNBAB2MFMHFIo+OAB8CmCBAXL87FPIpVa9AMo1uhpPBEBvcnFtwA2gGt+cGYxZsuvfswC6AfgAuRGIYADoAYUNDBhw6WGAkZnIAX0oxcWZ4R2DjalNzYThrOzgMqRk5YJLSuwB3YAATGAALYPwARgAGLoBSfAAaGzsUoZSgA).

## Update

OK, so what you really want is a dynamic set of keys, based on the object literal given, and you're already aware of the function solution, but you don't want to use it. However, it appears that under the current limitation of TypeScript, there simply cannot exist a better solution, and here's why.

First of all, it is clear that if two objects are of the same (non-generic) type, then they must have exactly the same members (possibly optional, but still the same set of keys). Therefore the only possible way for your different objects to have different key constraints later on, is for them to have types that are technically different. Obviously, generic types will be your best option, where the generic parameter leads to different key constraints.

So let's say we define a generic type as such:

```
type StyleSet<T extends string> = {
    [k in T]: React.CSSProperties;
}
```

But then, at least for the current limitation of TypeScript, it cannot automatically infer the generic parameter without using functions. For example, you cannot write:

```
const a: StyleSet<> = ... // generic parameter must be explicitly given here
```

Because for now there's no such a thing as "partial type inference"; type inference only works when we completely omit the type, and when it can be inferred from the assigned value. One possibility, as you know, is our function solution:

```
function set<T extends string>(s: StyleSet<T>) { return s; }

const a = set({
    container: {
        width: "100%"
    }
});
```

And then in this case our `a` is inferred as `StyleSet<"containter">`. Yes, you'll have to wrap every object literal in our function `set()`, but as we've just analysed, your only alternative is to explicitly give the generic parameter:

```
const a: StyleSet<"container"> = {
    container: {
        width: "100%"
    }
};
```

Which is clearly worse, especially when you have multiple keys in one instance. With the function solution, all keys will be inferred at once:

```
const b = set({
    propA: { ... },
    propB: { ... }
});
// b will become StyleSet<"propA" | "propB">
```

Comment: I know this way, the problem is the keys are not predefined.

Comment: I've update the answer... You might be disappointed but really that's the best we got for now.

Comment: Thank you so much. Funny enough... this works like a charm for functions. If you have a function instead of an object, you can just use `ReturnType` of the function and it works. But for objects no? strange.

Comment: Partial inference has been proposed in the past, although without much progress. See this github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242

Answer (score -1):

You are creating `StyleSet` [Index Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types). And if closely look at it, it does not know anything about exact key names, it just knows that, key can be anything which is string.

Typescript also knows that much of information. When you assign `StyleSet` to `const k`, you loose the information of key names. Further on in the code, typescript does not know that `k` contains `container` field.

What you could do is, if you know static list of keys that should be available in the `StyleSet` then you can capture that in the type itself. With index types, you ll not be able to access its fields statically.

Comment: hahaha exactly you described the whole point of my question. What I am missing is that I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: If you dont know keys statically then how do you expect typescript to know them?